# Save google log-in with Chrome Driver

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, gmail

Hey I did a short script that logins on google.
Every time it has to do the login as the infos are not saved. Is there any way to save the login infomations in order to avoid logging in every time but only when the authentication is expired?

I would do something like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opt, executable_path=r'')
driver.get('https://www.gmail.com')
form = driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId")

if form==None:
   #do something else
else:
     login()
```

But do not how to save the tokens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your login information like cookies are stored in chrome profile.

so to avoid re login prompts . Use the default profile which you uses for logging into gmail.

user-data-dir considers profile as default , and you don't have to specify that . If its something else specify it through profile-directory argument

**Step to know profile path:**

**open** : chrome://version in address bar

[image]

**Now to use this :**

```
chrom_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
```

**Note;**  you should give only till user data don't need to specify user data\Default

**Update:**

**copy** the user data folder completely to eg c:\tmp\newdir

open the copied user data (newdir) and search for folder called Default . This is the profile folder.

**Now to use this :**

```
chrom_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=c:\\tmp\\newdir")
```

Comment: Doing this I cant leave my default chrome window open, is there anyway to use the script while my chrome window is open?

Comment: you copy the Default folder to a newfolder and use that profile instead

Comment: Do I have to include also the default folder of the new directory (eg. "C:\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\New User Data\New default") or until the new user data folder (eg. "C:\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\New User Data")? Thanks

Comment: if the folder name of your profile is default then you don't have to give it , it is detected automatically. Else you have to give it . As you are passing the entire user Data you just need user-data-dir only, dont need "--profile-directory=Profile 1"